# The output is not as I want

Tags: python, python-2.7, output

I'm very new to python. I am writing code to generate an array of number but the output is not as I want.

The code is as follows

```
import numpy as np

n_zero=input('Insert the amount of 0:  ')
n_one =input('Insert the amount of 1: ')
n_two =input('Insert the amount of 2: ')
n_three = input('Insert the amount of 3: ')

data = [0]*n_zero + [1]*n_one + [2]*n_two + [3]*n_three
np.random.shuffle(data)
print(data)
```

The output is as follows :

```
Insert the amount of 0:  10
Insert the amount of 1: 3
Insert the amount of 2: 3
Insert the amount of 3: 3
[0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want the following output:

```
0031032030202110000
```

Thank you

Comment: You got a list of strings. Convert it to a string with `''.join(data)`.

Comment: `n_zero` is a str. You can't multiplique a str with a list. Try `int(n_zero)`

Comment: print(''.join(map(str, data)))

I did this and it works! Thank you!

Comment: @lbellomo He must be using Python 2, so `input()` evaluates the input.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems. Here is the corrected code, the explanation:

```
import numpy as np

n_zero=int(input('Insert the amount of 0:  '))
n_one =int(input('Insert the amount of 1: '))
n_two =int(input('Insert the amount of 2: '))
n_three = int(input('Insert the amount of 3: '))

data = [0]*n_zero + [1]*n_one + [2]*n_two + [3]*n_three
np.random.shuffle(data)
s = ''.join(map(str, data))

print(s)
```

First, you need to convert the input from a string to an integer. I added `int()` in every input line.

Then you have to convert the list you got, `data` to a string for the representation you want. I did it with

```
s = ''.join(map(str, data))
```

because I like to use map when it makes the code concise. You can use a list comprehension if you like.

And eventually, print 's', of course, not `data`.

Comment: He must be using Python 2, otherwise he'd have gotten errors from `*n_zero`. So he doesn't need to call `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just after `np.random.shuffle(data)` line

add one more line of code which converts list into string

```
data = ''.join(data)
```

This would do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list of *numbers*

```
    data = [0]*n_zero + [1]*n_one + [2]*n_two + [3]*n_three
```

create a list of *characters*

```
    data = ["0"] * n_zero + ["1"] * n_one + ["2"] * n_two + ["3"] * n_three
```

and then instead of

```
    print(data)
```

use

```
    print "".join(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* the output like this

```
0 0 3 1 0 3 2 0 3 0 2 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

(with spaces between numbers) is *acceptable* for you, use

```
for i in data: print i,
```

(note the *comma* at the end) instead of your printing statement.